how to fix "cant open mysql file" error in commandline
error image MySQL fails to open the sql text file i downloaded.
I wanted to load a sample database into MySQL to learn MySQL queries
but it fails to open file,
note: I downloaded the file in another drive other than where my MySQL server and workbench are located but i have tried cutting and pasting the file to that drive with no avail.

You cut off a part of the error message. Add complete error message text formatted as text, not as a screenshot.

failed to open file error is  usually caused by incorrect file path or not having access rights to the file. None of which is a programming problem.
